# Why give me this error? AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'a'

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I need create a node, this node must be Subsriptor and Publicator.
But, I have this error.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/prueba/src/listener_3.py", line 71, in <module>
    listener()
  File "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/prueba/src/listener_3.py", line 63, in listener
    m= data.a
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'a'
```

My code is this:

```
import time
import rospy

from prueba.msg import Num
from prueba.msg import Num2
from prueba.msg import Num5
from prueba.msg import Num6
from std_msgs.msg import String

global a,b, callback, callback2, data, data1
a=0
b=0
c=0
data1=0
data=0
def callback(data):
    global a,b
    a = 5 + data.num
    print a
    print ""
        
    return a
    
def callback2(data1):
    global a,b
    b = 8 + data1.num2  
    print b
    return b

def listener():
    global a, b,c
    
    rospy.init_node('listener3',anonymous = True)
    rospy.Subscriber('topic_3',Num,callback)
    rospy.Subscriber('topic_4',Num2,callback2)
    pub5 = rospy.Publisher('topic_5',Num5,queue_size=10)
    pub6 = rospy.Publisher('topic_6',Num6,queue_size=10)
    m= data.a
    n= data1.b
    pub5.publish(m)
    pub6.publish(b)
    #rate.sleep()
    rospy.spin()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

I modified package.xml and CMakeList.txt, as the tutorial of "msg" explain.

I hope, any answer.
Thank You

---

Edit: Thanks, for your answer.

Effectively, my error is in python. I need to use the value of the variable "a and b" of the callback and callback2 function, in the listener function. But first, I got an error: "global name" xx "is not defined", so I declared them at the beginning of the program. But it does not work. I need those variables to publish them through a topic to another node.

In this node, I need receive and send variables. I don´t know, if this lines are good.

```
rospy.init_node('listener3',anonymous = True)
rospy.Subscriber('topic_3',Num,callback)
rospy.Subscriber('topic_4',Num2,callback2)
pub5 = rospy.Publisher('topic_5',Num5,queue_size=10)
pub6 = rospy.Publisher('topic_6',Num6,queue_size=10)
m= data.a
n= data1.b
pub5.publish(m)
pub6.publish(n)
```

m and n values are the variables that I need call of the callback function.

I would appreciate if you helped me with that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289253/why-give-me-this-error?--attributeerror:-%27int%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27a%27/) by [AlexLF](https://answers.ros.org/users/34750/alexlf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-22**:
Please do not post answers unless you are *answering* your own question. For everything else, edit your original post (using the `edit` link/button) or post comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is really a Python issue, not a ROS one, but:

> ```
> global a,b, callback, callback2, data, data1
> ```

```
[..]
data=0
[..]
def listener():
    [..]
    m= data.a
    [..]
```

The variable `data` is just an integer, not an object, or some other composite structure. You cannot index into it, nor use the dot operator to select contained fields.

I believe you are expecting the `data` *argument* to `callback(..)` (which may or may not have a field called `a`, depending on the message IDL) to be available to you in `listener()`, but that is not how this works.

---

I'm also rather puzzled by the the `global a,b,...` line at the top of your program. Those variables are already in the global scope, so what is it you're trying to do?

If I may suggest, it might be good to try and find some good Python books or online tutorials. With just a little Python experience I think you'll find that things (such as `rospy`) start to make a lot more sense.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexLF](https://answers.ros.org/users/34750/alexlf/) on 2018-04-21**:
Thanks, for your answer.

Effectively, my error is in python. I need to use the value of the variable "a and b" of the callback and callback2 function, in the listener function. But first, I got an error: "global name" xx "is not defined", so I declared them at the beginning of the program.